Wireguard and Ubuntu 22.04. Forcing traffic from port 25 over VPN
So Im hosting a server in a docker container which is a client in a VPN network. I Cant send any egress traffic out of port (say ummm 52) through the host. That box is a client to a wireguard server. If i set up the client config:
[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

Then i can egress port 52, no problem.  If I change that to say:
[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24

Then the server doesnt know it should send traffic from ANY ip using port 52 for egress out of that VPN instead of the local machine.  Im using Ubuntu 22.04 for this on the docker host.  What is the best way to get around this?  (Forward any traffic trying to egress over port 52 through the VPN)
To add to this, I'm decent with ubuntu/networking/firewalls but when it comes to iptables or any complex routing like this im a total newb.

So, do you mean you want only traffics originated from (but are probably "replies") that host (container) with source port being 52 (tcp or udp?) to leverage the tunnel, while all other traffics from it should leverage the link that connects it and the "local machine"?

All traffic should use the host default interface.  EXCEPT port 52.  Anything trying to initiate or respond to traffic on that port should go through wireguard.

What you're looking for is "policy routing". You can use policy routing to route traffic that matches certain characteristics like destination port differently than the rest of your traffic.
The general steps for policy routing with WireGuard are:

Set AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0 for the peer to which you want to send this traffic (or use whatever range of IP addresses to which you'll be sending this traffic).
Add routes corresponding to this peer's AllowedIPs setting to a custom routing table, instead of the main table. When using wg-quick, wg-quick will do this automatically for you (for all of the interface's peers) if you use the interface's Table option to specify a custom routing table ID.
Set up one or more policy-routing rules to match your traffic and direct it to your custom routing table. Again with wg-quick, you can embed these rules in a WireGuard config file via PreUp (or PostUp) scripts to create them automatically when the interface is started.

For example, the following WireGuard config file will route to the interface's abc... peer all IPv4 traffic sent to TCP port 52 (via a custom routing table with an ID of 123):
[Interface]
PrivateKey = xyz...
Address = 10.0.0.234/24
Table = 123
PreUp = ip rule add ipproto tcp dport 52 table 123 priority 456
PostDown = ip rule del ipproto tcp dport 52 table 123 priority 456

[Peer]
PublicKey = abc...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0


The problem is when i set:
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
This problem becomes moot because then ALL traffic is sent through the VPN. I really appreciate the thought out answer though and I've been waiting for days lol.  The problem is i need to allow the host to use its own interface for everything except for port 52, which needs to get routed through wireguard.

@Nimrod5000 Setting Table= to a numeric value triggers different behavior. (Although for 0.0.0.0/0, the reason is not because the route would be added to the main table otherwise, but that wg-quick's own ip rules would be suppressed.) Apparently you are looking to match the source port though.

@TomYan Oh wow i glazed right over that part haha!  So does that Table= apply the routing to only that routing table then?

Well, as I said, in the case of 0.0.0.0/0, the route would be added to an alternate route table anyway, regardless of whether you have Table=auto (the implicit default) or Table=some_number. It's just that for the latter, wg-quick's "magic". i.e., some routing policies / ip rules that look up the alternate table for route will not be added. (So are some iptables/nftables rules too.) You may check with ip rule to see the difference. (If a route table is not looked up at all, then the routes inside it would be effectively "dormant".)

@TomYan Ok i think this is starting to make a little more sense.  Im now running into issues though with other ports not being forwarded correctly or something.  When i use the setup you gave me, i was no longer receiving traffic from my wg interface for my docker containers on other ports.  My VPN server sends me traffic for a couple websites since i dont have a static ip

@Nimrod5000 Change of routes or routing policy won't really stop ingress traffics from being able to come in. (Well, there's something called reverse path filtering, but I don't think it'd be cause of the problem you just mentioned.) You probably just need some more routes / routing policies for certain traffics to be routed into the tunnel to reach the server. You'll either need to figure it out yourself or give us more specific details.

@TomYan what more information do you need?  It works fine forwarding the ports from server to client if I don't set the Table= and I give it a specific IP for the peer instead of 0.0.0.0

@Nimrod5000 I mean, by the sound of My VPN server sends me traffic for a couple websites since i dont have a static ip, it doesn't seem that you "just need it to" Forward any traffic trying to egress over port 52 through the VPN. You'll need to either let us know what other traffics need to go into the tunnel, or add the necessary extra ip rules yourself. Any (non-loopback) traffics that are not matched by a rule that looks up the alternate route table will be routed as per the routes in the main table.

@Nimrod5000 For example, if you "also need" all the requests and replies for x.y.z.w to take the VPN path, you can / need to add ip rule add to x.y.z.w lookup wg_table_number, or, ip route add x.y.z.w dev wg_interface_name (in which table main is implied when no otherwise is specified).

@TomYan YOU ARE THE MAN!!  TY soooo much!

@TomYan Hey i realized im having another issue where the incoming traffic is no longer being routed to docker.  I can see a bunch of SYN commands coming in but my container isnt picking up on them.  Is this from something else you think?  BTW i GREATLY appreciate all the help so far!  EVen if you dont respond this was freaking awesome!

Freakin HUGE shoutout to the gents helping me here!  Below is the completed wg client im using that works:
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.100/32
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <priv_key>
Table = 123

PreUp = ip rule add ipproto tcp dport 52 table 123 priority 456
PreUp = ip rule add to 10.8.0.1 lookup 123
PostDown = ip rule del ipproto tcp dport 52 table 123 priority 456
PostDown = ip rule del to 10.8.0.1 lookup 123

[Peer]
PublicKey = <pub_key>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <wg_server_ip>:51820

